# Creating and populating a vector within a loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class Player which have id,color and name.

I also have a vector of Players.

I would like to create 50 Players. 10 Players per color. Meaning 10 playrs in red, 10 in black etc..

I can do somethihng like :

```
Player player1(1, "black", "player1");
```

And then add it to the vector :

```
players.addPlayer(&player1);
```

But I don't think that manually creating and inserting them is the best way to do this.

I would like to create a loop in which I will create the player and add him to the vector.I just don't know how to give a different color to every 10th player..

Comment: Why, simply use two loops. One outer loop, that loops over the five colors. One inner loops, that loops ten times, one for each player. Then insert a player, specifying the color from the outer loop. Problem solved.

Comment: So I guess create an enum for the colors and loop through them in the outer loop? I'll have 5 enums but I want 10 times eeach enum. I am not sure how to go about that

Comment: Have you [tried asking your rubber duck for help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: what's the `players.addPlayer`? Aren't you using `std::vector`? What is the type of `players`

Comment: `const char* happyLittleColors[] = { "midnight black", "titanium white", "dark sienna", "phthalo blue", "alizarin crimson" };`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you wanted the players to be numbered as 1 - 10 five times or as 1 - 50 once, you can fix it if needed. The trick with colors is to just make an array that gets indexed based on `i / 10`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Player {
public:
    const unsigned    id;
    const std::string color;
    const std::string name;

    void display() const { std::cout << id << ' ' << color << ' ' << name << '\n'; }

    Player() = delete;
    Player(unsigned i, const std::string& c, const std::string& n) :
        id(i),
        color(c),
        name(n)
    {}
};

int main() {
    const char* colors[] = { "red", "black", "blue", "green", "white" };

    std::vector<Player> players;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        players.emplace_back(Player(
            i + 1,
            colors[i / 10],
            "player" + std::to_string(i + 1)
        ));

    for (const Player& player : players)
        player.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty example of what you might do, the code has an outer loop the iterates through the colors and creates 10 player instances per color.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
    Player(int id, string color, string name) : 
        _id(id), _color(color), _name(name) {
    }

    int getId() { return _id; }
    string getColor() { return _color; }
    string getName() { return _name; }

    string toString() {
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << _id << "," << _color << "," << _name;
        return ss.str();
    }
private:
    int _id;
    string _color;
    string _name;
};

int main() {
    vector<Player> players;
    int playerId = 0;
    for (auto color : {"black", "blue", "green", "cyan", "red"}) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            playerId++;
            players.emplace_back(Player(playerId, color, "Player" + to_string(playerId)));
        }
    }

    for (auto p : players) {
        cout << p.toString() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The colors can be stored in a vector dynamically and then accessed using a vector iterator, which is a faster method. A loop for iterating over vectors and another to create 10 players per color will be sufficient for your requirement. Sample to your approach is available below, the player naming can be changed as per your requirements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Player
{
public:
    Player(int id, std::string color, std::string name);
    void Display();
    int _id;
    std::string _color;
    std::string _name;
};

Player::Player(int id, std::string color, std::string name)
{
    _id = id;
    _color = color;
    _name = name;
}

void Player::Display()
{
    std::cout << _id << ' ' << _color << ' ' << _name << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<Player*> players;
    std::vector <std::string> colour;
    colour.push_back("Black");
    colour.push_back("Red");
    colour.push_back("Orange");
    colour.push_back("Yellow");
    colour.push_back("Blue");

    int id = 1;

    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = colour.begin(); it != colour.end(); it++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            std::string player = "player";
            std:: string name = player + std::to_string(id);
            Player* player1 = new Player(id, (*it), name);
            players.push_back(player1);
            player1->Display();
            id++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 3 points of feedback: you leak each `Player`, you should just have `auto colour = {"Black", Red" ... }` etc, and your outer `for` loop should just be `for (const auto& c : colour)`. So nothing overly serious but all things that would improve your answer